# C# WPF Dynamically Creat group of controls WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Let's say that I have a class such as following:

```
Public MyChart
{
  private string ChartName{get; set;}
  private List<MyChartSeries> ChartSeries{get; set;}
}
```

And then under my ViewModel I have a `public List <MyChart> Charts`

What I will do is that I use **Chart Name** to create a new TextBlock which will contain this string value (something like a header) and then under it I will create a new chart which will be populated from **ChartSeries** (it will be more complex, yet for explanation purposes it is good enough).

Number of Charts can vary depending on the input file. I can create this 'group of controls' via code; however I believe there should be some way how to do it dynamically via MVVM pattern (so that I don't have to manually loop over my Charts collection and do everything myself).

I would like to ask for a direction how to start with this, as I have never done this before...so I don't even know where to start. I do know that I will most probably have to create a **UserControl** but that's pretty much all.

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Comment: So you propose that I would adjust my ListBox DataTemplate to display charts instead of text?

Comment: @RobertJ. So you have to actually draw the chart? Why don't you use a third party library to do so? Then you can just bind your data to it.

Comment: yes, I do use a library for charts. will try, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ItemsControl control. In your case itemscontrol inside ItemsControl where the topmost will have ItemsSource databoumd to ’Charts’ and the inner to ’ChartSeries’

In mvvm instead creating Items in xaml you create just ItemTemplate and Specify ItemsSource. Wpf will then create items for you. If you used ObservableCollection instead of List you could dynamically add and remove charts and chartseries and ItemsControl would create and remove items in ui automatically.

Comment: By any chances you might have any links that would help me to understand this? I am not quite sure I fully understood this concept